# limit of a sum: $\sum_{n} = 1+x+2x^2+3x^3+...+nx^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I have a sum 
$$\sum_{n} = 1+x+2x^2+3x^3+...+nx^n$$
and asked to simplify it and given $|x|<1$ determine the limit as $n \to \infty$

My first impression is that this is a simple geometric series but I have a mental block as to what is the common ratio.
I assume that it was simply $\sum_{n=0}^\infty nx^n$ but when I plug in values to test it the first terms don't seem intuitive. But following from this would the common ratio be x.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico–geometric_sequence#Infinite_series

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-can-i-evaluate-sum-n-0-inftyn1xn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\text{Let }\;
S = 1+x+2x^2+3x^3+...+nx^n.
$$

$$
\text{then }\;xS=x+x^2+2x^3+3x^4+...+nx^{n+1}
$$

$$\text{Subtract: }\:
S(1-x)=1+x^2+x^3+\ldots+x^n-nx^{n+1}
$$

$$\text{Note that }\;
x^2+x^3+\ldots+x^n
$$
is a geometric series, with first term $x^2$, common ratio $x$ and $n-1$ terms.

You can compute that geometric series and simplify the overall expression for $S$.

For $n \rightarrow \infty $ then $x^n \rightarrow 0$ when $|x| < 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$ 1+x+x^2+x^3+.... = \frac {1}{1-x}      $$

Differentiate to get

$$ \frac {d}{dx} (1+x+x^2+x^3+....)=\frac {1}{(1-x)^2}         $$

term by term differentiation  implies

$$            \frac {d}{dx} (1+x+x^2+x^3+....)= 1+2x+3x^2+....                     $$ Therefore

$$  1+2x+3x^2+.... = \frac {1}{(1-x)^2}    $$

Multiply by x

$$   x+2x^2+3x^3+...=\frac {x}{(1-x)^2}$$

add $1$ to bothe sides

$$ 1+x+2x^2+3x^3+... =1+   \frac {x}{(1-x)^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

On the interval $(-1,1)$, the infinite sum $1+x+x^2+x^3 \ldots$ $=\frac{1}{1-x}$, which we will write as $y(x)$.

The sum you wrote is $1+ x \left(\frac{dy(x)}{dx}\right)$.

Answer (score 0):

$$ 1+x+2x^2+3x^3+... = $$

$$(1+x +x^2 +x^3+...)+ (x^2 + x^3 +x^4+...)+ ( x^3 + x^4 +x^5 +...)+...=$$

$$ ( \frac {1}{1-x}) +(\frac {x^2}{1-x})+   (\frac {x^3}{1-x})+...=$$
$$   ( \frac {1}{1-x})(1+x^2 +x^3 +...)=$$

$$ ( \frac {1}{1-x})(1+\frac {x^2}{1-x}) =$$

$$ \frac {1-x+x^2}{(1-x)^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

I have already shown in another post that:

$S=1+2x+3x^2+4x^3+ . . .nx^{n-1}=\frac{{nx^{n+1}-(n+1)x^{n}+1}}{(x-1)^2}$

Multiplying bth sides by x we get:

$x.S=x+2x^2+3x^3+ . . .nx^n  ⇒x.S+1=1+x+2x^2+3x^3+ . . .nx^n =s $

so the answer is:

$s=x.S+1=x.\frac{{nx^{n+1}-(n+1)x^{n}+1}}{(x-1)^2}+1=\frac{{nx^{n+2}-(n+1)x^{n+1}+x+(x-1)^2}}{(x-1)^2}$